# Delete rows in table built dynamically

Tags: javascript, ajax, html-table

I've been stuck on this stupid problem for a few days now. I guess it's not complicated but I might need someone's help...

Here is the thing: I start with an empty table in my html page. There is only the head with the name of the columns. Then, I get JSON data thanks to php, and I fill my table by creating a new row and new cells as follows:

```
for (var j = 0; j < jsonVal.length; j++){
            var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
            tr.insertCell(-1).innerHTML = "<img src=\"" + jsonVal[j].image + "\">";
            tr.insertCell(-1).innerHTML = jsonVal[j].name;
            tr.insertCell(-1).innerHTML = jsonVal[j].rating;
        };
```

Now, all I want to do is to update this table according to some parameters (ordered by name or rating, only 5 lines etc...)
To do so, I want to delete all the rows I currently have to put with the new data. BUT I can't find a way to delete them. Here is my deleting code:

```
var currentTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var rowCount = currentTable.rows.length;
for(var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++){
    currentTable.deleteRow(i);
}
```

I get the following error:

> IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount

Is that the correct way to do it?

PS: sorry for such a long explanation.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I only needed to change i to 1 in my for loop as follows:

```
var currentTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var rowCount = currentTable.rows.length;
for(var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++){
    currentTable.deleteRow(1);
}
```